# Proving that "negative of a linear functional is also a linear functional"

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Can you please give a simple proof of a negative of a linear functional being a linear functional itself? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you state the definition of a linear functional?  Then, can you state what it is you need to show for the proof?  Perhaps doing these things will help you prove it.

Comment: You can either use/prove that the composition of linear functionals is again a linear functional, or check the definition for this special case.

Comment: What have you tried? Do you know definition of linear functional? For $f$ a functional, do you know how $-f$ is defined?

Comment: Just use the definition of a linear function.I.e. a function is linear if f(v+cu) = f(v)+c*f(u), where u,v are vectors and c is from field. Nothing much to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is straightforward to check that if $L_1, L_2$ are linear operators then
so is $L_1 \circ L_2$.

It is straightforward to check that $n(x) = -x$ is a linear functional.

Hence given some linear $L$, the map $n \circ L$ is linear.

Comment: I can get behind this answer. It still insists that OP puts some effort.

Answer (score 0):

May $f$ be a linear functional.
Then $f$ due it's linearity fulfils the homogeneity and additivity properties.

Let $a \in \mathbb R$ and let $v$ be a vector:
$$f(a\vec v) = a f(\vec v)$$

Hint:

Is there a different approach to write $-f$ with a scalar $a$ as $a f$.